# Rectangular problem to use for benchmarking a large dense linear solver?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerics

Can anyone suggest a rectangular problem I can use for evaluating a large dense linear solver? ($m,n>1000$) IE, ideally something that's easy to download and has been evaluated for some solvers already.

Comment: Is $m>n$ or $n>m$?  Are you solving the problem in the least squares sense?  Do you want a minimum norm least squares solution or will any least squares solution do?

Comment: I have a solver (based on https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.01108) and wanted to evaluate it out on a realistic problem (number of rows greater than number of columns)

Comment: Have you look at Tim Davis' collection of matrices? I don't know whether it includes dense matrices, but it's a nice collection.